# WM_GETICON: ICON_SMALL vs ICON_SMALL2

Tags: winapi

Official Microsoft docs for `WM_GETICON`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-geticon

I am confused about `ICON_SMALL` vs `ICON_SMALL2` for Win32 message `WM_GETICON`:

- `ICON_BIG`: "Retrieve the large icon for the window."
- `ICON_SMALL`: "Retrieve the small icon for the window."
- `ICON_SMALL2`: "Retrieves the small icon provided by the application. If the application does not provide one, the system uses the system-generated icon for that window."

My guess:

- `ICON_BIG` corresponds to `WNDCLASSEX.hIcon` via `GetClassLongPtrW(hWnd, GCLP_HICON)`

  - `WNDCLASSEX.hIcon`: "If this member is NULL, the system provides a default icon."
- `ICON_SMALL` corresponds to `WNDCLASSEX.hIconSm` via `GetClassLongPtrW(hWnd, GCLP_HICONSM)`

  - `WNDCLASSEX.hIconSm`: "If this member is NULL, the system searches the icon resource specified by the hIcon member for an icon of the appropriate size to use as the small icon."
- `ICON_SMALL2`

  - If `WNDCLASSEX.hIconSm` is non-`null`, return `WNDCLASSEX.hIconSm`.
  - If `WNDCLASSEX.hIconSm` is `null`, then return (small) system default.

Reading the official documentation carefully, I do not understand the difference between `ICON_SMALL` and `ICON_SMALL2`.

Comment: If you don't specifically set a small icon, the system will scale one from the large icon. `ICON_SMALL` only returns an icon that you have set (either via the class or via `WM_SETICON`) - if the small icon was synthesized by the system, `ICON_SMALL` returns null, whereas `ICON_SMALL2` returns it either way.

Comment: No, you'd have to send WM_SETICON first.  If the small icon was not set with this message then ICON_SMALL returns NULL but ICON_SMALL2 returns the synthesized small icon.